# no instance of overloaded function "std::make_unique" matches the argument list, but works with unique_ptr constructor

Tags: c++

If I do:

```
std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter> avFrameUniquePtr(av_frame_alloc());
```

I get no errors. Observe that

```
av_frame_alloc()
```

returns `AVFrame*`

However if I do

```
std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter>  avFrameUniquePtr = std::make_unique<AVFrame,AVFrameDeleter>(av_frame_alloc());
```

I get

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::make_unique" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (AVFrame *)
```

For me it should be ok. What's happening?

Comment: std::make_unique allocates a new object. Does AVFrame has a constructor that accepts a pointer to another AVFrame? Do you want to end up with two such objects, one allocated by std::make_unique and the other by av_frame_alloc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's happening?

Unfortunately, [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) can't specify the deleter type. Its 2nd template parameter is used for the type of the list of arguments passed to it. The code fails because you specify it as `AVFrameDeleter` explicitly, but pass `AVFrame*`, they don't match.

> Unlike `std::make_shared` (which has `std::allocate_shared`), `std::make_unique` does not have an allocator-aware counterpart. A hypothetical allocate_unique would be required to invent the deleter type D for the `unique_ptr<T,D>` it returns which would contain an allocator object and invoke both destroy and deallocate in its operator().

On the other hand, the following code works (even it's not what you expect).

```
// the 1st template parameter is specified as AVFrame
// the 2nd template parameter is deduced as {AVFrame*}
// construct a std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, std::default_delete<AVFrame>>
std::make_unique<AVFrame>(av_frame_alloc());
```

Comment: I can't use a default deleter. There's no way of specifying a class member of type `std:unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter>`  and then initiate it in other places? What about doing like this: `std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter> avFrameUniquePtr(av_frame_alloc());` and then I simply call `avFrameUniquePtr.reset(av_frame_alloc())` instead of using `std::make_unique`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs If you can use initialize it directly like `std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter> avFrameUniquePtr(av_frame_alloc());` then it's fine, or you can construct an empty one like `std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter> avFrameUniquePtr;` then `reset` it later. Or you can make your own `make_unique`, it's not hard.

Comment: std::make_unique passes its arguments down to the constructor of the object being made. Unless AVFrame has a constructor that accepts a pointer to another AVFrame, this isn't going to work, regardless of any deleter.

Answer (score 3):

`make_unique` is for allocating an object (forwarding its arguments through to the constructor) and returning a `unique_ptr` to that object. Since `av_frame_alloc` already allocates the object, there's no reason to allocate again.

What you want is exactly what the constructor of `unique_ptr` does—to take ownership of that pointer returned by `av_frame_alloc`. `make_unique` isn't the right tool for when you want to transfer ownership.

Now you mention in a comment that this is a class member. You can deal with that through braces (the language disallows parentheses in this context specifically) or the member initializer list of the constructors:

```
class Foo {
    // A
    std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter> avFrameUniquePtr{av_frame_alloc()};

    // B
    std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter> avFrameUniquePtr;
    Foo() : avFrameUniquePtr(av_frame_alloc()) {}
};
```